# Files not being uploaded to server and variable are said to be undefined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Before I start please be aware that I will prepare the statements at a later stage.
Moving on I am attempting to have a file be uploaded and be stored in a folder named the days date.
I tried this code but nothing is uploaded and it is not showing as uploading and when I am adding it to the DB it is saying `Notice: Undefined variable: randomname` all the other fields are being inserted no problem. `Header.php` contains all the SQL configuration data.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("header.php");
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
mysqli_select_db($con,$DATABASE);

    //Checks if the submit button has been pressed.
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        //Sets the target dir where the image will be moved.
        $target_dir = "/public_html/domain/php/uploads/"  .  date(d/m/Y) . "/";
        //If folder does not exist, create the folder.
        if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
            mkdir($target_dir, 0755, true);
        }
        //Sets the upload value to 1 ; if the value keeps the value of 1 when passed all the tests, the file will be uploaded.
        $uploadOk = 1;
        //Checks what file extension the image has.
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["photo_url"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Creates a random name in MD5
        $randomname = md5(uniqid(true) . $_FILES["photo_url"]["name"]) . "." . $imageFileType;
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["photo_url"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_dir . $randomname)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["photo_url"]["size"] > 800000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large. Max image size is 8mb";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo_url"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $randomname)) {

                //Echo's that the file has been uploaded.
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["photo_url"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }

$sql="INSERT INTO photo(photo_project_id,photo_section,photo_subsection,photo_date,photo_post,photo_desc,photo_url,photo_dir)VALUES('$_POST[photo_project_id]','$_POST[photo_section]','$_POST[photo_subsection]','$_POST[photo_date]',now(),'$_POST[photo_desc]','{$randomname}','$_POST[photo_dir]')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

echo $sql;
if($con = new mysqli($SERVER, $USER, $PASS, $DATABASE)){ echo "success"; }else{ echo "error: " . mysqli_error($con); }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @chris85 I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code provided, `$randomname` won't exist if the `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {` check fails, but it will still try to do the database insert no matter what. That is only checking to see if there was an HTML element named "submit" with an assigned value in form that was POSTed.

First of all, I would move the code starting at `$sql = ...` inside the if check. Also, a better if check might be to look for something that's a required field:

```
if (isset($_POST['photo_project_id'])) {
```

or better yet, see if it's an actual HTTP POST:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
```

Comment: I will try your the HTTP post method, the submit button is obviously being pressed. So I dont think that is what is causing this.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the submit button is being pressed or not, if it doesn't have both a name and value set, it won't be passed along in the POST data. To be passed in the POST data, it needs to be something like: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="anything">`

Comment: so if I put that in instead on the form that will fix it?

Comment: Yeah, it should. Because it's just a posted field value, it doesn't need to be on the button itself, you could just add a hidden input with the same thing. That's why I think it's kind of pointless, it's really just looking for a field that was sent called "submit", that doesn't actually relate to the submit button itself at all.

Comment: Ended up working with some other modifications to MKDIR (path was incorrect) and date (it thought I was dividing so I used - instead)

Comment: That makes sense, looking at it now I can see some problems with it.

Comment: I should clarify I needed to implement your fix as well.